# Is there any performance benchmark for Thrift on HBase?

Tags: c++, performance, benchmarking, hbase, thrift

I have a system that may writing huge data to hbase.
The system is written by c++ and found out that hbase have thrift interface for other languages.

My question is,

1. Is there any performance benchmark for Thrift on HBase?
2. What is the most disadvantage compaire with java native api?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend these recent two blog posts on this topic:

1. [HBase + Thrift performance part 1](http://blog.thisisfeifan.com/2012/06/hbase-thrift-performance-test.html)
2. [HBase + Thrift performance part 2](http://blog.thisisfeifan.com/2012/06/hbase-thrift-performance-test-2.html)

The two posts give detailed performance measurements of using Thrift with HBase.